# Vue - Force Rerendering Of All Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, model-view, rerender

I've wrote a plugin for *Vue* and have some issues on rerendering. In fact there is a new filter, which translate a given text by the global defined language. When the language changes, the text should be translated again. Cause there is no event queue for filters here, I want to force all components to rerender themselves, if the language changes. So the filter function would be evaluated new.
I know that I can rerender a component itself with `vm.$forceUpdate()`. But how can I told the whole Vue component tree to rerender? Cause this only happens, if the user change the language, the performance issues should not be a problem, cause at least the user do not have to reload the whole page and can do this offline.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**`key` attribute**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) in the component root. Change it and the component tree will be rerendered.

[Per docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) (bold is mine):

> It can also be used to **force replacement of an element/component**
> instead of reusing it. This can be useful when you want to:
>
> - Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component
> - Trigger transitions
>
> For example:
>
> ```html
> <transition>
>    <span :key="text">{{ text }}</span>
> </transition>
> ```
>
> When `text` changes, the `<span>` will always be replaced instead of
> patched, so a transition will be triggered.

Comment: Used some similar solution. Thanks for the Inspiration.

Comment: This helped me solve an issue for another problem when I had a computed prop with getter and setter and swapping props but the values didnt change. God bless your eternal soul